# How SO Facebook Twitter Google Plus sharing works

Tags: discussion

I have seen on Stack Overflow there are option to **"share a link to this question via email, Google+, Twitter, or Facebook."**

I know we can post on social network site from their own sharing tools/app. Most of the time author/website post their content on social networking sites.
But in SO, User can share this on their own profile.
How its work?

Appologies, if i sound stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Most of the time author/website post their content on social networking sites.

I'm not sure that's necessarily the case. I see a lot of sharing links on blogs and news articles. Readers of those articles can click on them to share them to their own Facebook or Twitter page. The author of the content is not the only person who does this. This is the same way these links work on Stack Overflow. Anyone can share a post that they find interesting.